# Docker compose configuration for database with separate data image

Tags: sql-server, database, docker, docker-compose

Currently, I have a docker-compose file for spinning up SQL Server database and it has a volume configured to persist the data on disk.

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: MsSqlServer
    environment:
     - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
     - SA_PASSWORD=Password_01
    ports:
     - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
     - /tmp/docker-volumes/db:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

Instead, I would like to have 2 docker images. One with SQL Server only and another one which would contain the data so that I could later regularly pull just the data image (not the whole server).

What is the best way to configure this? I believe it can be somehow configured using volumes_from attribute? Does somebody know how exactly? Is there any other way how to configure it, for docker compose v3?

Comment: could you further explain the use case?

Comment: I would like to separate the database data from the SQL Server, to have them in separate images. The data image would be then maintained - new test data would be added there or the existing data would be modified, from time to time, by a maintainer. The other persons who would like to spin up the test database would then regularly pull just the updated data image. Not necessarily the image with the whole SQL Server, for each data update.
Is this possible?

Comment: Images are generally immutable, so they're not a good choice for database storage.  A container also runs a single program, so a container that only holds data but doesn't run anything in particular doesn't really make sense (ancient Docker setups aside).  I'd manage the data directory using ordinary tools like `tar` and `scp` here.

Comment: you could just use `tar` and distribute it using Github (if data usage is small) or with a shareable Google Drive link or some sort. You could also set up an `NFS` server and expose it to people who'd be interested in the data by IP and mount it to the container using [NFS mount for docker](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-mount-nfs-drive-in-container-simplest-way/46699)

Comment: I don't see a clean solution using Docker Compose here, for the reasons that @DavidMaze states. One option would be to look at Spawn (https://spawn.cc) which is designed to solve exactly this 'dockerized DB with data images' problem (disclaimer, I work for them). It sounds like a good fit for your problem though; you'd be able to create your data image, automate keeping it up-to-date and then create as many independent SQL Server instances from that data as you need for your team.